# 'Reversed shell' - pull shell commands from remote host with human-controlled input?

Tags: ssh, nc

I would like to connect to a remote machine, ideally over SSH, and then pull the commands from there.

To be precise, I would like make a remote machine connect to my local machine, where I would have an interactive console, send commands and see the output.
Functionally it would be similar to Windows Remote Assistant or what's the name.

I can imagine I would implement a HTTP server that would have a GUI, and on request, it would keep the connection forever and send any line that I type to the GUI; and receive everything the other side sends as its output. I would only have to take care of the HTTP headers. However, that's not too elegant.

Is there some such ready-made solution? Or perhaps using `nc` or some tool that would connect the TTY with a listening port?

Answer (score 5):

If you run:

```
socat "unix-listen:$HOME/.shell-access,mode=600,fork" \
      "exec:$SHELL,pty,stderr,setsid,ctty"
```

That allows you to do for instance:

```
socat -,raw,echo=0 "unix:$HOME/.shell-access"
```

locally, to connect and interact with that shell.

Then you can remote-port-forward it over ssh with:

```
ssh -R "/path/to/socket/on/host:$HOME/.shell-access" user@host
```

(assumes a relatively recent version of openssh (both client and server)).

And then `user` on `host` can interact with that shell by doing that

```
socat -,raw,echo=0 "unix:/path/to/socket/on/host"
```

Instead of running `$SHELL`, you could run `screen -xRS some-screen-session` to attach a given `screen` session so several people can see the same screen session.

Answer (score 2):

With traditional netcat.

server:

```
$ nc.traditional  -lvp 1234 -e /bin/sh
```

client:

```
$ nc -nv <ip> 1234
```

You can also forward the port via ssh.

Comment: That means exposing a shell running as you to anyone, so lets anyone who can connect to ip:1234 run any command as you on your machine without authentication.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like make a remote machine connect to my local machine, where I would have an interactive console

Create a listen on your locale machine:

```
socat file:`tty`,raw,echo=0 tcp-listen:PORT
```

Type the following command on the remote machine:

```
socat exec:'bash -li',pty,stderr,setsid,sigint,sane tcp:YOUR_IP_ADDRESSE:PORT
```